# replace \n string with real \n in lua

Tags: lua

Is there a way in lua when a string containing \n or \t given, that we are able to get the real meaning of \n(real new line) or \t(tab) to a string that would get pass on. This has to be done before printing as it would solve the problem! But I don't want to print the updated string!

I used gsub but don't know how to represent a actual new line. (A tab can be represented by some number of white-spaces)

Comment: I'm not sure what you have tried, but `s:gsub("\n","NEWLINE")` replaces all newlines with the string NEWLINE.

Comment: I don't have a single clue what you mean; can you give an example?

Comment: It sounds like your asking if you can have a `new line` in your string literal, you can do that with the multi line string constructor `[[ some string text ]]` a tab can be in an string literal.

Comment: `print((your_string:gsub("\\([nt])", {n="\n", t="\t"})))`

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace the two character sequence `\ ` followed by `n` with the single newline character `\n`? Or do you mean you want to replace `\n` with a "newline" conceptually the same way you can replace a tab character with spaces? If you mean the latter I dont think you quite understand why the newline character `\n` exists.

Comment: Sorry for not providing an example. I want if s = "hello\nworld" to become s = "hello                      world(in the next line). Hope you got that @DarkWiiPlayer

Comment: @Charith_32 `"hello\nworld"` *is* just that though; the `\n` gets replaced with an actual newline. Or do you get the string from somewhere else and it already includes the literal `\n`? If so, Egor Skriptunoffs answer should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Lua 5.3 Lua Reference Manual 6.4 String Manipulation string.gsub](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub):

> `string.gsub (s, pattern, repl [, n])`
>
> Returns a copy of `s` in which all (or the first `n`, if given)
>   occurrences of the pattern (see §6.4.1) have been replaced by a
>   replacement string specified by `repl`, which can be a string, a table,
>   or a function. `gsub` also returns, as its second value, the total
>   number of matches that occurred. The name `gsub` comes from Global
>   SUBstitution.
>
> If `repl` is a table, then the table is queried for every match, using
>   the first capture as the key.

```
local myString = "hello\\n\\tworld"
print(myString)
```

> `hello\n\tworld`

```
print((myString:gsub("\\([nt])", {n="\n", t="\t"})))
```

> ```
> hello
>   world!!!
> ```